# Sorting strings in word macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need help with writing a function which will take an array of strings and sort this into a new array of strings based on only the number characters in the strings (ascending)? 
say I have the following array of strings:

`"abc53ddd", "2zzz2yyy", "14"`

I will need them listed as

`"14", "2zzz2yyy" and "abc53ddd"`

as the number characters in the string are `14, 22 and 53.` 
I can strip the string into the number portions and sort the array but I can't recover the remaining characters to list them back in the right order...

Comment: have you already tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

Use ADO with disconnected recordset. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176578.aspx. It is fast and robust. IMHO, it is the best.

```
'recordset definition
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset 'must be reference "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects"
'OR use automation (without reference)
'Dim rst
'Set rst = CreateObject("ADOR.Recordset")

'fields definition - how many you want (name, type, lenght)
rst.Fields.Append "field1", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, 255
rst.Fields.Append "number", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adInteger

rst.Open

'add values, for example:
Dim rc As ADODB.Record
rst.AddNew "field1", "abc53ddd"
rst.AddNew "field1", "2zzz2yyy"
rst.AddNew "field1", "14"

'make numbers from string and store in field [number]
Dim reg As New RegExp
'OR
'Set reg = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
reg.Pattern = "\D" 'non-digit
reg.Global = True

rst.MoveFirst
Do Until rst.EOF
    rst!Number = Val(reg.Replace(rst!field1, "")) 'delete non-digit
    rst.MoveNext
Loop

'sort!
rst.Sort = "number ASC" 'sort by field1 ascending

'show output
rst.MoveFirst
Do Until rst.EOF
    Debug.Print rst!field1, rst!Number
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
```