# Code Efficiency/Optimaization and Sort 2D Array VB6

Tags: arrays, sorting, optimization, vb6

Can I get some help with optimizing my program? I'm trying to make my code as efficient as possible, and I also need help sorting a 2-D Array.

**PROGRAM ANALYSIS**

Write a program which will take in a list of ski jump competitors and their scores.
This list will then be stored in an external file.
For each jumper, remove the highest and lowest score then calculate the total of the remaining scores, outputting this total alongside the jumper’s name into a new external file
The file containing the competitor’s scores will be sorted from the highest to the lowest.
A function must be included.

**CODE:**

```
Private Sub cmdStart_Click()

'Declare Variables used to Store Values

Dim Names(5) As String

'2D Array used to Display Score
'Value 1 represents number of competitor, while value 2 is ScoreNumber
'i.e Score(2,5) Represents Score 5(out of 5) of competitor 2( out of 5)
'Sixth Value in Array used to store Total Score

Dim Score(5, 8) As Integer
Dim CompetitorPointer As Integer
Dim counter As Integer
Dim Filename As String


'Input Scores for each Competitor into an Array
counter = 1
For counter = 1 To 5
    Names(counter) = InputBox("What is the Name of Competitor " & counter & " ?")
        For scorecounter = 1 To 5
            Score(counter, scorecounter) = InputBox("What is score " & scorecounter & " of Competitor " & counter & " ?")
        Next
Next


For CompetitorPointer = 1 To 5
    maximum = FindMax(CompetitorPointer, Score)
    minimum = FindMin(CompetitorPointer, Score)
    Score(CompetitorPointer, 7) = maximum
    Score(CompetitorPointer, 8) = minimum
Next

'Find total Score of Competitor
For CompetitorPointer = 1 To 5
    CompetitorScore = 6
    TotalScore = Score(CompetitorPointer, 1) + Score(CompetitorPointer, 2) + Score(CompetitorPointer, 3) + Score(CompetitorPointer, 4) + Score(CompetitorPointer, 5)
    Score(CompetitorPointer, CompetitorScore) = TotalScore
    MaxMin = Score(CompetitorPointer, 7) + Score(CompetitorPointer, 8)
    Score(CompetitorPointer, CompetitorScore) = TotalScore - MaxMin
Next


Min_Index = 1
Max_Index = 5

'File manipulation Program
'Create File

Open "Z:\AHComputing\VB\PROJECT\File.txt" For Output As #1
intMsg = MsgBox("File opened")

'Sorting Algorithm

'Selection sort is a simple sorting algorithm that mimics the way humans instinctively sort.
'It works by first scanning the entire list to find the smallest element, swapping it into the first position.
'It then finds the next smallest element, swapping that into the second position, and so on until the list is sorted.

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim iMin As Long
    Dim iMax As Long
    Dim varSwap As Variant

For CompetitorPointer = 1 To 5
    Min = 1
    Max = 5
    For i = Min To Max - 1
        iMin = Score(CompetitorPointer, i)
        For j = (i + 1) To 5
            If Score(CompetitorPointer, j) < iMin Then iMin = Score(CompetitorPointer, j)
        Next
        varSwap = Score(CompetitorPointer, i)
        Score(CompetitorPointer, i) = iMin
        iMin = varSwap
    Next

    Print #1, Names(CompetitorPointer), Score(CompetitorPointer, CompetitorScore)
Next CompetitorPointer


Close #1

intMsg = MsgBox("File closed")

End Sub

'Used to Find Highest Score of Competitor
Private Function FindMax(CompetitorPointer As Integer, ByVal Score)
    maximum = Score(CompetitorPointer, 1)
scorecounter = 1
For scorecounter = 1 To 5
    If Score(CompetitorPointer, scorecounter) > maximum Then
    maximum = Score(CompetitorPointer, scorecounter)
    End If
Next
FindMax = maximum
End Function


'Used to Find Lowest Score of Competitors
Private Function FindMin(ByRef CompetitorPointer As Integer, ByVal Score)
    minimum = Score(CompetitorPointer, 1)
scorecounter = 1
For scorecounter = 1 To 5
    If Score(CompetitorPointer, scorecounter) < minimum Then
    minimum = Score(CompetitorPointer, scorecounter)
    End If
Next
FindMin = minimum
End Function
```

Can I get some help with sorting the array and can I get tips on refining the code to make it more efficient?
I was reading up on records and I was wondering if they'd be better for storing the values?

Please note that comments were included for my personal use, so you can just ignore them.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put the data into a database file (I use MS Access), then you can use SQL statements to sort, find max/min values etc.  This works really fast.  You don't need to run Access, everything can be done from inside VB6.  You can use Access to create an empty database file with the tables and fields defined.  Everything else can be done from inside VB6
John

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I'm completely unfamiliar with SQL statements, so i'll do some research into that and try to modify my code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

For sorting use **ADO with disconnected recordset**. You don't need a database on hard disk, it is all-in-memory solution. It is fast and robust, no experiments. See my older post about [sorting with ADO and disconnected recosrdet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16830534/2369384) with full example code.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, However I feel that using this may prove too complex for my level and I don't think i'll get any extra marks for using a data structure my teachers don't understand. And is storing in an ADO more efficient that using a record?

Comment: About complexity: yes, you have to learn basics of ADO. But then you will sort and get max/min by one row of code. About efficiency: ADO stores data in records. You can connect ADO object to physical database (MS Access, for example) or you can use it disconnected, in memory only, as is shown in my link. And the efficiency is really very, very good.